# Membership login asp.net with guid as username

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, guid

I'm creating a new ASP.NET MVC4 web application, which build partly on some old database tables from an old system.

In the User table the only unique identifier is a GUID value, and therefore I need to use this as "username" in the ASP.NET membership provider. Does anyone have a simple way to do this? I have tried a lot of different solutions, and this is really bugging me :)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Use NEWID() to generate the GUID value...from there you can get the GUID value, or so called username...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the use to login with 'guid', just few modifications in WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection() will enable this. Read this http://www.itorian.com/2012/11/adding-email-details-field-in.html. (at the bottom)

Comment: you would never use a GUID id as a username, perhaps as a USER ID.. generated behind the scenes.